# WebView Local Html And Canvas?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

So as for experiments, I was messing around with the WebView component and playing around with loading in local HTML files. Now what i want to figure out, is say i have a canvas element within my Local HTML file, and i'm rendering a game in the canvas. How do I communicate my React-Native code with the local HTML's canvas script? I've searched up how to communicate with HTML webview code and react-native and they say that WebView has a prop called injectedJavaScript that requires a string of code to execute to the webview. Check the docs here. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview

But how on earth would I handle a game from the canvas code in this instance with just the injectJavaScript prop??? Is there another way of allowing communication between my react-native code and the local HTML/JS webview code???

Side note also check this website, which also enhances my explanation of what i want aswell. Although i'm still not sure how to properly do my game/canvas code with stringified js code...
https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/12/27/injecting-custom-javascript-into-react-natives-webview/

Any of your guys's answers are worth so much too me right now, i've been trying to figure this thing out for a week now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between Java or Kotlin code to Javascript in `Android` in a `WebView` the only way would be via the annotation `@JavascriptInterface` which basically provides the defined method to the JavaScript code.

You can also call functions defined in Javascript from your Java / Kotlin code. However, I would advise you to bind those functions to `window`. So you have a function in JS like: `window.test()`.

There is also [this great Article](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) in the Android documentation which explains how to implement this.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your response, I'll mark this as most useful for now. I'm not quite familiar with Kotlin, but i will definitely check it out aswell as JavascriptInterfaces. I'll be sure to update you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! If the Android Documentation is unclear to you at some point or you are having trouble with understanding  certain thngs just ask me and I will hopefully be able to help you :)